# Window Onkeypress not working

Tags: javascript

The code worked the first time I tried it. I pressed "l" and the little error appeared like normal. I closed out of the website, ran it again, and it didn't work? Someone help:

```
    window.onkeypress = function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 76) {
        alert("Lol")
      }
    };
```

Comment: We are developers not fortune tellers. Its impossible to debug the code with the little information you provide.

Answer (score 1):

maybe the first time it worked because you pressed "L" (on caps-lock) and second time because you pressed "l".

how about:

```
window.onkeypress = function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 76) {
        alert("Lol");
      }else{
         console.log("key pressed: "+ event.keyCode);
      }
    };
```

then you can find out what happened, and remove the C.L after the debug

Answer (score 0):

Try printing `console.log(event.keyCode)` before you giveup... captial `L` keycode is 76 so remember `L!=l`

```js
window.onkeypress = function(event) {
   console.log(event.keyCode)
        if (event.keyCode == 76) {
        alert("Lol")
      }
    };
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. In console it showed me the "new" codes and those work (for l it was 108)

Comment: @ConlanRyan good to know that it worked.. remember the power of  console.log